# Forge (Trigger.io) facebook module getLoginStatus

Tags: facebook, trigger.io, forge

At [Forge.Facebook module](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/facebook.html) doc I can only see authorize, logout, api and ui function avaible from FB SDK. But it's et posible to get login status, like SDK's getLoginStatus, some how?

Comment: This is now available in our v1.4.17 platform - http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call forge.facebook.authorize and if the user has already logged in it won't open up the modal dialog again.

Since [v1.4.6](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-6) we also return the access_token.

Is there anything else that getLoginStatus gives you that you'd need through us?

**Update**: you can now also check whether a user is logged in without showing any prompt using our [forge.facebook.hasAuthorized method](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/facebook.html#forgefacebookhasauthorizedpermissions-audience-success-error).

Comment: I would like the posibility of only showing the login button if user is not already register. So calling forge.facebook.authorize when the user has not signed up will cause the facebook dialog to come up - which it not was I want - before they press the login button.
So forge.facebook.authorize would be good with a "do not show dialog" option but gives me an error instead :)

Comment: I see, yes we've added a ticket to add that feature and we'll report back here when it's complete.

Comment: Just updated the answer - see forge.facebook.hasAuthorized: https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/facebook.html#forgefacebookhasauthorizedpermissions-audience-success-error